# KeyError in Python Script

Tags: python

I've tried debugging this script but I'm not sure waht's causing the error.

```
list1 = ['<p>Text ([0-9]):(.*)</p>' ,'<p>Text2 ([0-9]):(.*)</p>','<p>Text ([0-9]):(.*)</p>']
list2 = ["<p class='text'>Text \1:\2</p>" ,"<p class='text'>Text \1:\2</p>","<p class='text'>TEXT ([0-9]):(.*)</p>"]
translation = dict(zip(list1, list2))


pattern = re.compile('(%s)' % '|'.join(dicts.list1))
file.close()
file = open(args.file,'r+')
def translate(match):
    return dicts.translation[match.group(0)] 
with open(args.file, 'r+') as output:
        with open(args.file, 'r+') as book:
            for line in book:
                output.write(pattern.sub(translate, line))
```

**Error:**

```
    return dicts.translation5[match.group(0)]
KeyError: '<p>Text 1:1-1</p>'
```

Comment: It's not regex. `dicts.translation` does not have `<p>Text 1:1-1</p>` key.

Comment: Full traceback should be included.

Comment: How would I make the lists act as a RE?

Comment: @NoahR: Use pattern as key, not the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to match a read line and see what regexp it matches so that you can apply appropriate change to it (also in regexp form). This approach *might* work but using a dictionary is redundant in this case.

The broad approach is

1. You match the line to compiled `pattern` to find a match.
2. Then you compare each pattern in `list1` to the matched string to see if it
   matches.
3. If it does you convert the matched string to the form in `list2`

Something like

```
list1 = ['<p>Text ([0-9]):(.*)</p>' ,'<p>Text2 ([0-9]):(.*)</p>','<p>Text3 ([0-9]):(.*)</p>']
list2 = ["<p class='text'>Text \1:\2</p>" ,"<p class='text'>Text \1:\2</p>","<p class='text'>TEXT ([0-9]):(.*)</p>"]
translation = dict(zip(list1, list2))
pattern = re.compile('(%s)' % '|'.join(dicts.list1))

def translate(m): 
    for x,v in translation.items(): 
        if re.search(x,m.group()): 
            return re.sub(x,v,m.group())

for line in book:
    m = pattern.findall(line)
    ret = translate(m)
    if ret is not None: 
        output.write(ret)
    else: 
        #No match. Echo back original line
        output.write(line)
```

Input

```
<p>Text 1:1-1</p>
```

Output

```
<p class='text'>Text 1:1-1</p>
```

There are probably other *better* ways to do it

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the text `'<p>Text 1:1-1</p>'` is not a key in your dict. As `dicts` is a free variable in your code, there is nothing more we can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Try match.group(1) instead. In regex results, group(0) is the entire matched string and groups 1 and following are the groups in the regex itself. In your case group(0) == `"<p>Text 1:1-1\</p\>"` and group(1) == `"1"`.

Comment: I switched match.group(0) to match.group(1) and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: It still returned `KeyError: '<p>Text 1:1-1</p>'`?

Comment: I can't figure out what your script is supposed to do so was just offering the fix for match. I probably shouldn't have jumped in here!

Comment: @tdelaney I think what he is trying to do is that he has built a dictionary of the form `'pattern':'repl'`. Presented with an input `<p>Text 1:1-1</p>`, he will search which key in the dictionary satisfies the pattern and then replace it (using `re`) with the corresponding dictionary `value`. Something like a dictionaried sed

Comment: Oh, I get it. The goal is to add the class="text" attribute to paragraph elements that match certain patterns. This might be better solved with an xml processor such as ElementTree. Use it to enumerate p tags, check for the desired pattern and add the attribute.